# Do you show up on the radar while shooting with Assassin but no silencer?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Do you show up on the radar while shooting with Assassin but no silencer?

For example, if you are using the ACR with no silencer, but you do have assasin on. Does assasin then allow you to not show up on the radar **apart** from when you are shooting.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Assassin only protects you from showing up to UAVs and similar "radar" sourcing devices when you are not shooting.  Only a silencer conceals you when shooting.

You can see from [this link](http://www.themodernwarfare3.com/mw3/perks-list/):

> Makes you undetectable by UAV, thermal scopes, Heartbeat Sensors and Portable Radars. You can still show up on the radar if you fire a weapon that doesn't have a silencer.

Note also that Assassin is not effective against Recon or the Recon Drone, although in my experience you do not get a targeting reticle on enemies using Assassin with the Recon drone, even though you can still tag them if you see them.

> Assassin doesn't protect you from the Recon perk or the Recon Drone killstreak.

Comment: As a side note, being in range of a friendly scrambler will give you most of the benefits of Assassin and Blind Eye (not the pro versions, though). I'm uncertain if it works against Thermal or Heartbeat sensors, but air support and UAV/AUAV will ignore you.

Comment: You still show a targeting reticle for recon drone when using Assassin/Assassin Pro. It may seem like you don't because many Assassin users also use Blind Eye.

Answer (score 1):

You won't show up on the radar with assassin on but everytime you fire with your unsilenced weapon you appear as a red dot. It's wise to use silencers when using Assassin because it defeats the purpose if you don't.